# Why can't I load Windows on my new hard drive in an Inspiron 1440?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I just had to install a new hard drive in my Dell Inspiron 1440.  The BIOS sees it, Diagnostics sees it with no problems, but Windows Install fails because it doesn't see a HD.  I have tried both Windows XP and Windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: What size is the hard drive? Did you initialize it already. Before you can format a hard drive, it needs to be initialized.

Comment: It might help if you post the exact make and model of the HDD in question. Can you edit your question and add this?

Comment: Since you're using BIOS make sure the drive is formatted in MBR not GPT. Good chance it's as @tlund says, a driver problem.

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be that you need an additional driver for the SATA chipset the laptop uses. You can download this from the manufacturers webstite and load it during the windows install.